# Signalr client not receiving messages after upgrading to 2.4.1

Tags: angularjs, signalr, signalr.client

I have updated the signalr version from 1.x to 2.4.1 in an angular project, The application is working without any issues in dev server but when deployed to other server the client is not receiving messages. There are no changes in the hub. My observation is that the previous version is using clientProtocol 1.5 and the new one is using clientProtocol 2.1. but why would it work in one region and not in the other?